# Store tuple as field in model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models:-

```
class A(...):
    id=...
    name=...

class B(...):
    setOfA=models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

What I want is that the setOfA be a 2-d array of A and date.
That is:-

setOfA = [[A1,date1],[A2,date2]]

How can I implement this?

Comment: I do not what that date is, but you can have third model having `date` and foreign key to `A` as fields and store the instance of that third model in M2M field.

Comment: date is just the date. Not a model. It was supposed to be date = models.DateField(). But I want it associated with an object of A

Answer (score 1):

You want custom relation model.

```
class A(...):
    id=...
    name=...

class B(...):
    setOfA=models.ManyToManyField(A, through='Relation')

class Relation(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    important_date = models.DateField()
```

Then to get result in format you mentioned:

```
foo = Relation.objects.filter(b=my_b).select_related('a')
result = [[x.a, x.important_date] for x in foo]
```

Comment: But the dates are not the same. Each A has a different date.

Comment: You can have unique date for every A that B references in M2M relation.